# Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope' - React Js Production Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

From React's documentation to make my application full PWA what I've done,
in `src/index.js`

```
serviceWorker.register();
```

in `package.json`, I've added homepage

```
"homepage": "https://react-test.devsenv.com/"
```

Assume that it is a fresh copy of `create-react-app`.

**Since, Service worker is not registered and the error saying -**

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '`importScripts`' on '`WorkerGlobalScope`': The script at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js' failed to load.
>       at https://react-test.devsenv.com/service-worker.js:14:1

I've searched lot in the internet. But not get the exact solution. One more issue if I'm ok, is the file is not readable - https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js of google's api ? It is not responding, if I hit the url from browser.

Any one can give me a tips, what I've to setup in my cpanel or whatever..

Comment: Can touch the file from here. Are you under some firewall?

Comment: I think so, but will it stop for a countries network, I'm in Bangladesh and it is not working most of the network here, is there any solution, do you know please?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Maybe try from an other device to see if your computer has a firewall blocking this page, or try to pass through a VPN or through Tor network (if these are legal in your country) to bypass your ISP blocking the access.

Comment: Yes, it's working from different region via VPN. Thanks. You can make the comments as an answer, I'll accept.